# Win32 per-filesystem cache tuning?

Tags: winapi

Does Win32 have any per-filesystem (NOT the global cache) data or file attribute tuneables, which can be set (i.e. via ISO C in the kernel *.sys driver code) by a mini-redirector filesystem provider?

We wrote a mini-rdr based filesystem, but the Win32 caching is quite poor compared to Linux, because the lifetime of cached data and filesystem attributes is quite short, even if the system only uses 8GB out of 96GB main memory.

Comment: *"Win32 caching is quite poor compared to Linux"* - Caching behavior in Windows isn't nearly as important as it is in Linux systems. With all I/O asynchronous by default in Windows, applications have vastly better ways to optimize in much more impactful ways.